Friends episode identification - the woman who is a chronic liar
In this episode there is a woman who tells so many amazing stories about her life that the regulars on the show stop believing her and are thinking she doesn't doesn't get out much or have friends.
I only seen a small part of the episode and it was a long time ago, so i may not be remembering correctly, but one conversation went like this...

the woman:  That's when i met George.
  one of the guys:  Washington?
  the woman:  Bush.
  one of the guys:  Close enough, they're both presidents.  So try another one on us.


Do you remember the woman being Dutch?

The only similar one I remember is TOW Ross's Tan from season 10, with Monica's annoying friend Amanda bragging about knowing famous people. But her appearance was brief and I don't remember a conversation like that (unless it's in some uncut version). Sure it wasn't HIMYM or something? ;)

I am really starting to second guess whether i know what i am talking about.  I read all the short descriptions about every episode and i see no hint of it.  Maybe i'm loosing it.

Another scene on the same episode that i'm wondering now whether it was Friends...
One of the guys, say Chandler, was talking to the woman at a bus stop and asked her "do you want to get some lunch?"  And she responds, "Sorry, but i'm not interested in dating you."  And Chandler hollers, "It's just lunch".
And then he starts to call her out on her stories and tells her "You don't get out much, do you?"
Am i really way off base here?  Is there such a friends episode?  You people would know better than me.

I'm well-acquainted with the show and unfortunately don't remember any scene like that.

I am fully convinced at this point that i am mistaking this sitcom with another one, you all would know.  Perhaps someone will read this and know what sitcom it pertains to.  Best regards.

@user3504324 It's definitely not Friends, sorry. And, if you remember the "bus stop scene" correctly, I can tell you it's not HIMYM or Seinfeld either.

I believe you're talking about Amanda Buffamonteezi.
She was the roommate of Phoebe and Monica before Chandler moved into the building. She appeared in the third episode of the 10th season: The One With Ross' Tan.

Possible to share some dialogues of her, as support to your answer? :)

I can't really find any to back up my answer. And I don't have the dvd's so I'll have to wait till said episode airs again :)

I did however find a video of her. Perhaps that rings a bell.

Is it The One With the Fake Monica?
That episode does not have anything related to George Bush, in fact she does not meet any of the guys.
But, it involves a woman being a chronic liar, and was living the life of Monica.

When the fake Monica is arrested, Monica tells her everything,
  including who she really is, and confides in her how she doesn't want
  to go back to being who she was. The fake Monica makes the real Monica
  see that she can't change her personality.

